# Solving an identity in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, parametrization

I have the following question:

> Let be $ \alpha : I \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 $ a regular curve
> parameterized by its arc length. Prove that it is verified that:
>
> $\alpha' \cdot \alpha'''' = -3 \kappa \frac{d\kappa}{ds}           $
>
> Where $\kappa$ denotes the curvature of $\alpha $.

My attempts were unsuccessful. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yeah, Me too :p

Comment: Silly comment. Why write prime everywhere for derivative but then write $d\kappa/ds$?

Comment: That is how it appears in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\alpha'\cdot \alpha' =1$ since this is an arc-length parametrisation. Then
$$0=\frac{d^3}{ds^3} \alpha' \cdot \alpha' = \frac d{ds}[2\alpha'\alpha^{(3)}+2\alpha''\alpha''] = 2\alpha''\alpha^{(3)} + 2\alpha'\alpha^{(4)}+4\alpha''\alpha{(3)}=2(3\alpha''\alpha^{(3)}+\alpha'\alpha^{(4)}).$$
Look more closely at $\alpha''\alpha^{(3)}$, this is $\frac12 \frac d{ds}\alpha''\cdot \alpha''=\frac 12\frac d{ds}\|\alpha''\|^2 = \frac12\frac d{ds}\kappa^2=\kappa \frac {d\kappa}{ds}$. Combine these two equations to get the desired equation.